# String with leading zeros in JSON?

Tags: python, json

I have a Python script that is using the requests module to post JSON to an API.  However, I am posting a hash that uses hex.  I'm running into an error when I use the following code:

```
r = requests.post('apiurl.com/do/stuff', json={"key": '0052ccca'})
```

The response is a 400 error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 
\'k0052ccca\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at 
[Source: [B@410c3139; line: 2, column: 23]"}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0) the recommendation is to treat the leading zeros as a string, but I'm already doing that and still getting an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json={"key": '0052ccca'})
>>> print(response.text)
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"key\": \"0052ccca\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "19", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.3"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "key": "0052ccca"
  }, 
  "origin": "38.98.147.133", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

There is nothing wrong with decoding that `json`, as you can see it is encoded correctly by requests:

```
>>> response.request.body
b'{"key": "0052ccca"}'
```

So the problem is server side (or your example code is too different from your real code to reveal the real issue).