# How to read text file to convert to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, readfile

I'm trying to read a text file contains dictionaries separated by comma, and convert to a list of dictionaries.

How can I do this with python?

I tried to read as json file or use split method

```
{
    "id": "b1",
    "name": "Some Name" 
},
{
    "id": "b2",
    "name": "Another Name"
},
....
```

result should be:

> [ {"id" : "b1", "name" : "Some Name"} , {"id" : "b2", "name" : "Another Name"}, .... ]

Comment: The main issue is that your data file isn't in a proper JSON format. You should make an edit to the source to wrap the list in square brackets `[`, `]`

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [How to add a character at the end of a JSON-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675367/how-to-add-a-character-like-at-the-end-of-a-json-object)

Answer (score 2):

If your file is not too big, you can do the following:

```
import json

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    result = json.loads('[' + file.read() + ']')
```

Comment: I don't think memory should be too much of an issue here. The built in JSON module is already not memory efficient. If memory consumption is a concern then OP should be using another library / approach.

Comment: As a minor side note, ensure that your final dict structure in the file doesn't have a trailing comma. Otherwise, you'll see something like `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use json module in python*

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), specified by RFC 7159 (which obsoletes RFC 4627) and by ECMA-404, is a lightweight data interchange format inspired by JavaScript object literal syntax (although it is not a strict subset of JavaScript).

json exposes an API familiar to users of the standard library marshal and pickle modules.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

In your case if your file is a valid json file
then you can use json.loads() method directly

```
import json

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    result = json.loads(file.read())
```

Comment: The example in his question is _not_ valid json. And this doesn't address his desire to create a list of dicts. See @Tomothy32's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow..!

If you are using a JSON file to store data, then I highly recommend the **Python JSON Library**. How to use it you ask..? Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

If you plan on using a Text file to store data, I recommend that you **store the data a bit differently than the JSON format**

```
b1,Some Name
b2,Another Name
.
.
```

This would make **reading the text file way easier**. Just use the `split()` command to separate the lines from one another and then use `split(",")` on each of the lines to separate the ID from the Name.

Here is the code:

```
list = open("filename.txt").read().split("\n")
dictionaryList = []
for item in list:
    id, name = item.split(",")
    dictionaryList.append({id:name})
```

Hope this works..! SDA

Comment: There's no reason to "store the data a bit differently than the JSON format", JSON is completely fine and very widely used. (However, OP's data is not valid JSON.)

Comment: That was if he was to use a Text file rather than JSON. He has mentioned that he wants a **list of dictionaries** and not a JSON as output

Comment: JSON can be a list of dictionaries.