# PHP json_decode() does not work with numbers starting with 0 (like 0123456)

Tags: php, json

In a JSON file I'd like to decode with PHP's `json_decode()` function I have items like this:

```
[{
  "id_regione":3,  
  "regione":"Calabria",
  "superficie":15221.9, 
  "num_residenti":1970521,
  "num_comuni":409,
  "num_provincie":5,
  "presidente":"Gerardo Mario Oliverio",
  "cod_istat":18,
  "cod_fiscale":02205340793, /* problem here */
  "piva":null,
  "pec":"dipartimento.presidenza@pec.regione.calabria.it",
  "sito":"www.regione.calabria.it",
  "sede":"Regione Calabria / Via Massara 2, 88100 Catanzaro"
}]
```

You see, the part `"cod_fiscale":02205340793` stops decoding with no apparent reason: but looking at PHP docs I found this in the changelog:

> 7.0.0  Rejected RFC 7159 incompatible number formats - top level (07, 0xff, .1, -.1) and all levels ([1.], [1.e1])

Oh, I see: `02205340793` seems an incompatible number format... Really it's not a number, it's a tax code (and I could potentially have problems also with phone numbers like 0935123456)

So, what's the best way to deal with these items? Convert everything to a string? And how?

Comment: Yes, since those numbers start with a 0, it's best to convert them to a string instead.

Comment: *"You see, the part "cod_fiscale":02205340793 stops decoding with no apparent reason"* There's a clear reason: The JSON is invalid, numbers can only start with a `0` if it's followed by `.`. See the syntax for numbers at http://json.org/.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, some systems (including both JS and PHP in some contexts) treat a leading zero as indicating an Octal (base-8) number.

Comment: Yes, convert to string. You can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or whatever else you feel like using. As @IMSoP said, they're treated as octal, which is *soooo* intuitive.

Comment: yes, you should convert it to strings. How to do? Give the json already correctly formatted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is JSON invalid if an integer begins with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The "no apparent reason" probably refers to the fact that `json_decode` doesn't raise any warnings, instead you have to call [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to find out what went wrong, which while potentially more useful, is uncommon in PHP, so people don't always know where to look.

Comment: Try this: `$data = json_decode($json,true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);`

Comment: @IMSoP - Ew. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers: sadly I can't do a manual number -to-string conversion because there are hundreds of items like the one I mentioned (anyway I yet wrote to JSON provider to warn for this problem)
Found the problem, the question remains: how to rapidly convert these "numbers" into strings given the whole JSON, please?