# Send integers through python data socket with fixed size

Tags: python, sockets, labview

I've been trying to send some integer values over socket to a LabVIEW client using `json.dumps` but as the numbers change the size of each field may change, I would like to know if there is a way to pad the number with '0' without turning it into a string when I do the json dump, as it adds `" "` to the packet send around each number.

Example:

```
data = json.dumps({"Data": str(52).zfill(4)]})
self.sock.send(data.encode())
```

This sends

```
'"Data":"0052"'
```

I want

```
'"Data": 0052'
```

Comment: Leading zeros are simply not allowed in JSON ints.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0/27361630#27361630

Comment: Why is it a problem that 'the size of each field may change' - is the LabVIEW client written in a way that can't handle this? Do you have access to the LabVIEW code?

Comment: I would like to send a big packet and do several tcp reads with a fix size to parse the information, as in every 7 values or so.

Comment: Then why JSON?; Why not send packets that lay out only what you need in a fixed string?

Answer (score 1):

As @jsonharper mentioned, technically what you're asking for is no longer JSON, [more on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0)

However, that doesn't mean you can't use the `json` library to do the bulk of the work for you!

You can achieve this by passing a custom encoder class to `json.dumps` like this:

```
>>> import json

>>> class MyInt(int):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '{:0>4}'.format(self)

>>> class MyEncoder(json.encoder.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, o):
...         if isinstance(o, MyInt):
...             return str(o)
...         return super(MyEncoder, self).default(o)

>>> obj = {'Data': MyInt(52)}
>>> json.dumps(obj, cls=MyEncoder)
'{"Data": 0052}'
```

You can do this with any class, but this *can* result in something that can't be decoded again with a strict JSON decoder.

See if you can get LabVIEW to read standard JSON, but if not, the above should work.

Comment: LabVIEW does have functions to read/generate json in string -> flatten/unflatten. If the JSON structure is known and constant, simply create a cluster reassembling the same structure, and let LabVIEW read the JSON data into the cluster and v.v.