# Newtonsoft.Json String to JSON conversion issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have below JSON input data coming from Queue

```
{
"ID": 0501,
"AssetId": "EFT0501"
}
```

JsonLint.com shows it's invalid JSON because number starts with 0.

In my .Net code, I'm able to parse this value but ID field value gets change.

**Code**

```
var test = JObject.Parse(message);
```

Output

```
{
"ID": 321,
"AssetId": "EFT0501"
}
```

Any suggestion Why is this value getting change? how to fix, If I can't change input format?

Comment: The number is interpreted as an octal number, 501 (octal) = 321 (decimal).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-a-leading-zero Seems like you will have to just store it as a string?

Comment: json does not support octal datatype, you have to change it to string or just receive it as decimal then change it back to octal..