# Unable to Read JSON Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When I'm reading JSON data -

Sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  JSON_TABLE(
          CONCAT('[', '351615,12345678', ']'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS tt
```

Error :

> "Missing a comma or ']' after an array element." at position 2.

When I remove `00` in front of integer it is giving proper result.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  JSON_TABLE(
          CONCAT('[', '351615,12345678', ']'),
          "$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
              ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
              )
      ) AS tt
```

Output:

```
351615
12345678
```

Can any one suggest me what I'm missing?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-a-leading-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_ARRAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) instead of concat a string to get a JSON array value:

```
-- single value
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_ARRAY('00351615'),
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(
    ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
  )
) AS tt

-- multiple values
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_ARRAY('00351615', '12345678'),
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(
    ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
  )
) AS tt
```

... or you escape the value with `"`:

```
-- single value
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  CONCAT('[', '"00351615"', ']'),
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(
    ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
  )
) AS tt

-- multiple values
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
  CONCAT('[', '"00351615","12345678"', ']'),
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(
    ids BIGINT(20) PATH "$"
  )
) AS tt
```

You can also check if your JSON value is valid, using [`JSON_VALID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid):

```
SELECT JSON_VALID(CONCAT('[', '00351615', ']')) -- 0 (not valid)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78753c0afef4bca43d407cb703565af9)

Comment: when I send multiple values my query is working but your answer is giving error I have modified my question please check

Comment: @mohan111 - added examples for multiple values.

Comment: while executing it is removing front "00" zeros .can you see once

Comment: if I pass values  like this (00351615,12345678) then it giving error I Can't add ('00351615','12345678') . can you suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, it is working:

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE('[{"x":"00351615","y":"2"}]',"$[*]" COLUMNS(xval VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.x",yval VARCHAR(100) PATH "$.y")) AS  tt;
```

Data type should be varchar instead of bigint as value with '00' prefix can not be stored in bigint.

Comment: To add multiple values you will have to add column also.

Comment: I have updated the answer with multiple values(x & y).