# Poison cannot parrse a json string that has 0 prefix

Tags: json, elixir, elixir-poison

Poison return invalid when I parse a valid json string that has `0` prefix.
For example,

`Poison.Parser.parse("{\"mynumber\":09315}")` returns `{:error, {:invalid, "9", 13}}`, but if I remove 0 prefix  `Poison.Parser.parse("{\"mynumber\":9315}")` returns `{:ok, %{"mynumber" => 9315}}`.

I would like to know why `"{\"mynumber\":09315}"` is not valid. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @DavidCullen thanks, it answers half of my question.

Comment: for workaround I just replace wiht `String.replace("{\"mynumber\":09315}", ~r/\"mynumber\"\:0*/, "\"mynumber\":")` before parsing it

Answer (score 0):

[Why is JSON invalid if an integer begins with a leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-a-leading-zero) explains the reason why `"{\"mynumber\":09315}"` is invalid.

for workaround I just replace wiht `String.replace("{\"mynumber\":09315}", ~r/\"mynumber\"\:0*/, "\"mynumber\":")` before parsing it