# spring boot validation for Long values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

This is class against which we are going to map the incoming request

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class FooRequest {
    @Size(max = 255, message = "{error.foo.name.size}")
    private String name;

    @Digits(integer = 15, fraction = 0, message = "{error.foo.fooId.size}")
    private Long fooId;

    @Digits(integer = 15, fraction = 0, message = "{error.foo.barId.size}")
    private Long barId;
    }
```

I have used `javax.validation.constraints.*` like above. If we send request like

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "fooId": "0001234567",
    "barId": "0003456789"
    }
```

Then It works fine and we are able to save the results in the database but if we send it like:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "fooId": 0001234567,
    "barId": 0003456789
    }
```

Then we are getting `400 Bad Request`. I am not getting it what wrong am I doing, I just want to ensure that user sends digits, having length between 1-15 and wants to map it against the `Long` variable. Is it because of `fraction` or because all these values are starting with 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second JSON is *not* a [valid json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361596/6486622) because of the leading zeroes.

#### Background

Spring uses [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library for JSON interactions.

The Jackson's `ObjectMapper` by default throws if you try to parse the second JSON:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.readValue("{\"name\": \"Test\", \"fooId\": 0001234567, \"barId\": 0003456789}", FooRequest.class);
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed
 at [Source: (String)"{"name": "Test", "fooId": 0001234567, "barId": 0003456789}"; line: 1, column: 28]
```

One can allow leading zeroes via the [`JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html#ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS, true);
        FooRequest fooRequest = objectMapper.readValue("{\"name\": \"Test\", \"fooId\": 0001234567, \"barId\": 0003456789}", FooRequest.class);

        System.out.println(fooRequest.getBarId());
    }
}
```

Or in spring via the Spring Boot's `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.parser.allow-numeric-leading-zeros=true
```

then, the second JSON will be parsed successfully.

#### Why does it work with the first JSON?

Because by default Jackson's [`MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS) is turned on.

From its javadoc:

> When feature is enabled, conversions from JSON String are allowed, as long as textual value matches (for example, String "true" is allowed as equivalent of JSON boolean token `true`; or String "1.0" for `double`).

---

> because all these values are starting with 0?

So it turns out that, yes, but for a *slightly* different reason

Comment: Thanks @denis-zavedeev.It worked with, "spring.jackson.parser.allow-numeric-leading-zeros=true"