# Error in VS Code [Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.]

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

While changing any setting in Visual Studio I'm getting an error like this:

```
  Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.
```

In the settings.json There is a problem as:

```
     Expected Comma JsonC(514)
```

Error Code:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the settings.json file. The issue is about a missing comma.

Comment: You missed a comma in your `settings.json`. Please copy and paste your `settings.json` content to this question

Comment: Paste your `settings.json` file into an online json linter - it'll probably show exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Correcting errors pointed out by vscode on `settings.json`  solved it.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest to validate your JSON in an online JSON validator like [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) for better info where the problem lies.

Also, as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709480/json-file-error-in-visual-studio-code-expected-comma-json514) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-a-leading-zero), that leading `0`'s on a number would also cause this kind of issue.

> If you have a number, don't ever store it with leading zeroes. If you
> have a value that needs to have a leading zero, don't treat it as a
> number, but as a string. Store it with quotes around it.

Here is an example:

> Invalid
>
> ```
> {
>   "attribute": "// numeroConta",
>   "operator": "=",
>   "value": 0030152201
>
> }
> ```

[image]

> Valid
>
> ```
> {
>   "attribute": "// numeroConta",
>   "operator": "=",
>   "value": "0030152201"
> }
> ```

[image]

Please provide your `settings.json` if this is not the case.

Comment: All cool and nice... but what about files that you have NOT edited? I'm just having this error, and it's the second time I used this editor. I didn't even knew where to find these JSON files.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most common causes for this is presence of comments inside JSON file. While vscode itself loads config with json-with-comments format, the sync part fails and when you use the GUI to configure settings it fails to update the `settings.json` file, even if you will not see any error/warning reported on the file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to open settings.json and add `,` on the end of

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00000000"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a comma at the end of the main curly brackets, but VS Code wasn't alerting to it specifically:

```json
{
    ...
}, // <---
```

Answer (score 0):

@Satyam Shukla you can edit your json and add this:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "xyz.ur.remove.id": "linux"
    },
    "git.ignoreLegacyWarning": true,
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv:true,
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": "bin/bash",
    "update.mode": "none",
},
```

it will disable vscode gets updated.