# JSON file error in Visual Studio Code: Expected comma json(514)

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm having a strange problem with Visual Studio Code.
I have the following JSON file that has a problem:

```
         {
             "attribute": "// numeroConta",
             "operator": "=",
             "value": 0030152201

         }
```

The problem is accused of "value" in the second number zero. The problem is as follows:
Expected commajson (514)
I found nothing in my searches. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have leading 0's on the number, you will need to make is a string and enclose it in "

```
{
  "attribute": "// numeroConta",
  "operator": "=",
  "value": "0030152201"
}
```

Otherwise remove the leading 0's, leading 0's that are not directly followed by a decimal point (i.e. 0.2 is fine) are not seen as numbers in the JSON format, see the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-a-leading-zero) issue here.

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem.