# json.load(filename) does not parse the file due to an Integer starting with 0 after a call from a REST API

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest

I am coding using Python, Flask, pandas. I am reading data from a REST API.

When I get the data from the REST API, the `dispenserId` used to be an Integer meaning that each value started with a number different from `0`.

This weekend, I received `dispenserId`s starting with a `0` (zero) character, so calling `json.load(path_to_filenamen)` *does not* parse the JSON file anymore due to errors.

See the sample

```json
{
    "result": {
        "dispensers": [
            {
                "dispenserId": 00000,
                "dispenserName": "1st Floor",
                "dispenserType": "H2",
                "status": "Green",
                "locationId": 12345
            },
            {
                "dispenserId": 98765,
                "dispenserName": "2nd Floor",
                "dispenserType": "S4",
                "status": "Green",
                "locationId": 23456
            },
            {
                "dispenserId": 00001,
                "dispenserName": "3rd Floor",
                "dispenserType": "H2",
                "status": "Green",
                "locationId": 34567
            }
           ]
       }
}
```

I receive `Exception has occurred: TypeError string indices must be integers` when I call `data["result"]["dispensers"]`.

How can I indicate to the JSON parser that the `dispenserId` is a string instead of an Integer?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27361565/3001761 - a number with a leading zero isn't really valid JSON, you should try to get that fixed upstream.

Comment: @jorsharpe I do agree with you but this isn't like I do have access to the developers of the API platform. Your proposal was on my task list though.

Answer (score 0):

Few things :

1.
your dispensers collection is not closed (no closing squarre braket, so it cannot work)

2.
since you got integers, you should not get that much zeros. you should have :

```
"dispenserId": 0,
```

or

```
"dispenserId": 1,
```

Once you got this corrected, `a["result"]["dispensers"]` will work just fine, undepending of the values of `"dispenserId"`.

OR :

The values should be given as strings :

```
"dispenserId": "00000",
```

and then convert them into integers :

```
int(a["result"]["dispensers"][0]["dispenserId"])
```

But anyway, your json file does not respect the json format.

Comment: thank you for your comment but I didn't copy/paste the entire json file. The oroginal file HAS a correct format.
The issue doesn't come from the json format.

Comment: Well, if in your json you have keys / values such as : "dispenserId": 00001, then the format is not right. Hence, the json.load function cannot behave properly.
You should either have : "dispenserId": "00001" or "dispenserId": 1

Comment: What you could do if you cannot change the source, is a preprocessing of your file, removing the "0" padding before numbers using regular expression, and then load your file into the json format

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should "clean" your file, by deleting all non wanted "0" and convert into Json format :

```
import re
import codecs
import json

pattern = "(:\s*)0*(\d)"
with codecs.open(path_to_filenamen,"r","utf-8") as f:
    myJson = json.loads(re.sub(pattern,'\\1\\2', f.read()))
```

The myJson var is in Json format, you can therefore use `myJson["result"]["dispensers"]`

Comment: Parsing with regular expressions is fragile, it's entirely possible that pattern would appear inside real data.

Comment: I agree, but considering the data involved, it is most unlikely.
And as said, the best would be to ask for a proper Json....